# How to transfer a SQL query to Microsoft.Crm.Sdk kind of query?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have a query from old Dynamics CRM 4.0 and need to write a new query in asp.net for data from Dynamics 365 (cloud). I know how to select a table with asp.net but no idea how to create a query for a more complicated logic with "group" and "select from select". Please advise and thanks.

Here is the query that I would need to create:

```
select sub.new_paymentid from
(select t.New_paymentId,MONTH(t.New_TransactionDate) as    TransMonth,COUNT(1) as MonthCount                                        
from New_transaction t
inner join New_payment p on t.new_paymentid = p.New_paymentId
where t.New_Status = 4 and (p.New_PaymentStatus != '5' and p.New_PaymentStatus != '6' and p.New_PaymentStatus != '8' )
and (p.new_alreadyfollowup != 1 or p.new_alreadyfollowup is null)
and New_TransactionDate >= convert(nvarchar(5),YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,-3,New_TransactionDate)))+'-' +convert(nvarchar(5),month(DATEADD(MONTH,-3,New_TransactionDate)))+'-1'
group by t.New_paymentId,MONTH(t.New_TransactionDate)
) sub 
where sub.MonthCount = 2                            
  group by sub.new_paymentid                             
  having COUNT(1) >= 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, You cannot achieve subquery concept in single CRM fetchxml or query expression.

Instead you can retrieve your subquery resultset, ie EntityCollection from CRM using fetchxml or query expression first. Then use LINQ or some C# way to filter / aggregate it in your code.

[Read more](https://softnovation.wordpress.com/2016/07/15/linq-query-on-entitycollection/)

Comment: Do the whole query with LINQ would be possible and easier?

Comment: @autopenta It’s a separate question about your dataset & expected result, after seeing that probably straight LINQ query can be achieved.